# PHP create pyramid pattern string contain numbers

Tags: php, string, loops

I want result like below that rows can be dynamic.

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

I tried like below

```
$a=5;
for ($i=1; $i<=$a; $i++){
   for ($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++){
      echo $j; 
   }
   echo "</br>";
}
```

Getting result like below.

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Please help me.

Comment: did you notice some pattern in your question. Sequence continues like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7..... So it suggests that a separate variable should be used to track the current sequence element

Answer (score 4):

I think you need a seperate variable to hold the counter

```
<?php
$a=5;
$num = 1;

for($i=1;$i<=$a;$i++){
   for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
      echo $num++;  // echo and increment the counter
   }
   echo "</br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just few modification needed

```
$number = 1; // counter
$a=5;
for($i=1;$i<=$a;$i++){
   for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++, $number++){ // increment number 
      echo $number. ' '; // space 
   }
   echo "</br>";
}
```